# Assert that movement works in my Raycasting engine

Tags: python, graphics, ascii, raytracing, raycasting

I am following the raycasting engine tutorial by javidx9 (the tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW8skO7MFYw), but I am writing it in Python instead. Note that I am stuck at around the 20-minute mark. He is able to achieve movement (back and forth, forward and backward, etc), but I am absolutely stumped as to why this is not working in my version. I have no error messages, I have tried setting variables such as the ray angle as constants, and I have tried modifying the map to see anything else than the standard bars appearing; but it doesn't seem to budge! All of the dependencies are built-ins, so it would be easy to test. Could someone more experienced with raycasting math tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
# Source.py

import os, sys, time, math, curses

"""Global variables"""
##########
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 120, 40 # os.get_terminal_size()# 120, 40# os.get_terminal_size()  # 120 : 40
screen = []


# for _ in range(40 * 120):
for _ in range(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT):
    screen.append("")


player_x = 8.0
player_y = 8.0
player_angle = 0.0

MAP_HEIGHT, MAP_WIDTH = 16, 16

FOV = math.pi / 4
DEPTH = 16.0

map_ = ""

map_ += "################"
map_ += "#..............#"
map_ += "#..............#"
map_ += "#........####..#"
map_ += "#........#..#..#"
map_ += "#........#..####"
map_ += "#..............#"
map_ += "###............#"
map_ += "#..........#...#"
map_ += "#...#..........#"
map_ += "#..........#...#"
map_ += "###....#.#.....#"
map_ += "#..............#"
map_ += "#..............#"
map_ += "#..............#"
map_ += "################"

COLOR = "\033[48;5;{}m{}\033[0m"
##########

def make_screen():
    for index, char in enumerate(screen):
        yield "\n" if index % SCREEN_WIDTH == 0 else char

def get_char(stdscr):
    stdscr.nodelay(True)
    char_num = stdscr.getch()
    if char_num != -1:
        return chr(char_num)


def main():
    global screen, player_angle, player_x, player_y

    time_1 = time.time()
    time_2 = time.time()

    while True:
        for char in make_screen(): print(char, end = "")

        time_2 = time.time()
        elapsed = float(time_2 - time_1)
        time_1 = time_2


        key = curses.wrapper(get_char)
        # key = input(">")
        # key = "a"
        time.sleep(0.2)

        if key == "a":
            player_angle -= 0.8 * elapsed
        elif key == "d":
            player_angle += 0.8 * elapsed
        elif key == "w":
            player_x += math.sin(player_angle) * 5.0 * elapsed
            player_y += math.cos(player_angle) * 5.0 * elapsed
        elif key == "s":
            player_x -= math.sin(player_angle) * 5.0 * elapsed
            player_y -= math.cos(player_angle) * 5.0 * elapsed  

        os.system("printf '\033c'")

        for x in range(SCREEN_WIDTH):
            ray_angle = (player_angle - FOV / 2.0) + (float(x) / float(SCREEN_WIDTH)) * FOV
            # ray_angle = 30.0
            print("ray angle", ray_angle)

            distance_to_wall = 0.0 
            has_hit_wall = False

            eye_x = math.sin(ray_angle)
            eye_y = math.cos(ray_angle)

            while not has_hit_wall and distance_to_wall < DEPTH:
                distance_to_wall += 0.1

                test_x = int(player_x + eye_x * distance_to_wall)
                test_y = int(player_y + eye_y * distance_to_wall)

                if test_x < 0 or test_x >= MAP_WIDTH or test_y < 0 or test_y >= MAP_HEIGHT:
                    hit_wall = True
                    distance_to_wall = DEPTH
                else:
                    if map_[test_x * MAP_WIDTH + test_x] == "#":
                        hit_wall = True

            ceiling = int(float(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2.0) - SCREEN_HEIGHT / float(distance_to_wall))
            floor = SCREEN_HEIGHT - ceiling

            shade = 0

            if distance_to_wall <= DEPTH / 4: shade = 207
            elif distance_to_wall <= DEPTH / 3: shade = 208
            elif distance_to_wall <= DEPTH / 2: shade = 209
            elif distance_to_wall <= DEPTH: shade = 210

            for y in range(SCREEN_HEIGHT):
                if y < ceiling:
                    screen[y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x] = COLOR.format(34, " ")
                elif y > ceiling and y <= floor:
                    screen[y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x] = COLOR.format(shade, " ")
                else:
                    screen[y * SCREEN_WIDTH + x] = COLOR.format(34, " ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```